# Execution flow of the statement

Tags: c++

Recently I came across this code block

```
 char *arrayOfStrings[]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
 char *(*ptr)[]= &arrayOfStrings;  // LINE A
```

Basically the code was to sort the above character array .
Line A **DOES NOT** generate any error . I don't get what exactly is happening here in Line A .

--> char ***(*ptr)** = &arrayOfStrings

What actually executes first ? Thanks!

Comment: There's no complex "execution". That line just declares a variable and initializes it.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed first"?

Comment: Use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org) when you are puzzled by C declarations: [`char *(*p)[]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+*%28*p%29%5B%5D)

Answer (score 1):

It just declares and initializes a variable of type a pointer to an array of pointers to char.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb with C types is that the declaration of the variable resembles how the variable is used. In this instance, `*(*ptr)[0]` (that is, `*((*ptr)[0])`) is `M`.